# The function of cv2.min

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision

I'm new to computer vision and OpenCV, so please mind the immature language. Can someone explain me what's the function of cv2.min?

I have this code that coverts from BGR to RGV (red, green ,value) from OpenCV book:

```
   b, g, r = cv2.split(src)
   cv2.min(b, g, b)
   cv2.min(b, r, b)
   cv2.merge((b, g, r), dst)
```

where ***src*** and ***dst*** are source and destination vectors for the image.

My specific questions are:

What is cv2.min doing to ***b*** in both the iterations? How are values being assigned to ***b*** since it's being evaluated two times for both ***r*** and ***g*** ?

Please let me know what's happening in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Can someone explain me what's the function of cv2.min?*

Look at the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#min):

> Python: `cv2.min(src1, src2[, dst]) → dst`
>
> The functions `min` calculate the **per-element minimum of two arrays**, or array and scalar

---

*How are values being assigned to b since it's being evaluated two times for both r and g ?*

You can break down like this:

```
cv2.min(b, g, b1)  # b1 contains the minimum values between b and g
cv2.min(b1, r, b2) # b2 contains the minimum values between b1 and r
b = b2
```

---

*What is cv2.min doing to b in both the iterations?*

The *i-th* element of `b` will be the minimum element in `b(i), g(i), r(i)`:

```
# Pseudocode
for each row
    for each col
        b(row, col) = min( b(row, col), g(row, col), r(row, col) )
```

---

However, this probably this is not correct, since the V value in HSV is computed as `max(R,G,B)`, and the order of your channels is inverted. To get RGV color space you need to do this:

```
b, g, r = cv2.split(src)
cv2.max(b, g, b)
cv2.max(b, r, b) 

# now 'b' contains the 'v = max(r,g,b)'
cv2.merge((r, g, b), dst)
```

Comment: I wish I could up vote the answer. So well explained. Thank you for taking some time out of this to explain.